# How do I know if a variable is private?

Tags: javascript

I've never understood private variables. I know how to make them, (using the Module Pattern, right) but I don't see what's so private about them. I illustrated an explanation on jsFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/fufWX/

Can you explain how that `_private` variable really is private when it is still accessible from the outerscope? And what are the use for private variables in the first place!? Thanks.

```
var Module = (function() {
    var _private = "My private variable";
    return {
        get: function() { return _private; },
        set: function(e) { _private = e; }
    };
})();

var obj = {};


// How is that variable private when I can simply obtain it like this:
obj.get = Module.get; // ??
obj.set = Module.set; // ??

obj.get(); // "My private variable"
```

Comment: Please include code in the question instead of just linking to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a truly private variable in JavaScript. There are only local variables.

In your example, `_private` is "private" because, outside of the anonymous function, it is only accessible via the `get` and `set` functions your have provided. Without those functions, `_private` would be totally inaccessible outside of the anonymous function.

---

Further reading:

- [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)
- [OOP in JS, Part 1 : Public/Private Variables and Methods](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS.html)